# On what SE site should I post a question about a copyright question concerning a sound?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

If I have a copyright question about a sound effect, what site should I post it on?

It seems like the law site but I am not sure.

Comment: That is [a great guess](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3369/57957).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copyright questions, including those about sounds, are well within [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com)'s scope.

The [copyright tag](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) is the second most active tag on the site.

Just make sure that your question is a [general law question](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/302/32651) and not [asking for specific legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/32651).

Comment: Thank you, but my question is centered around a certain sound, not the law.

Comment: @cs1349459 perhaps giving an example question would allow us to help better.  That said, if you _are_ looking for legal advice, there's no site for that on SE.